# replace XML tags value in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

Hi I am a xml file like this.

```
  <parameter name="END_DATE">20181031</parameter>
```

I want to replace this tags value to some other value I tried like this.

```
dt=$(awk -F '[<>]' '/_DATE/{print $3}' test.xml)
```

I extracted the tags value.

I have another variable value like this.

```
newdt=20181108
```

Now I need to replace this value to the extracted value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a tool like `xmllint` to process XML, not `awk` (or `sed`, or any of the standard line-oriented tools.)

Comment: As per @chepner 's comment it's best to use a XML-specific tools. For example using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) you'd run the following command: `newdt=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//parameter[@name='END_DATE']/text()" test.xml)`

Comment: The use of `awk` or `sed` need extremely precise knowledge of the exact serialization used for the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Chepner is right that `awk` or `sed` are not exact tools for xml in case you are NOT having `xmlstarlet` in your system then try following.

```
echo $newdt
20181108
awk -v dat="$newdt" 'match($0,/>[0-9]+</){$0=substr($0,1,RSTART) dat substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: That will replace any/every number field with this new date, though I agree the questioner is ambiguous.

Comment: @GemTaylor, agreed, if OP clarify the question more I could add more conditions to it.

Answer (score 0):

If sed works for you -

```
sed -Ei 's/( name="END_DATE")>20181031</\1>20181108</' test.xml
```

And xml parser is probably a better idea, though.

If you need to embed the variable -

```
sed -Ei "s/( name=\"END_DATE\")>20181031</\1>$newdt</" test.xml
```